# How to get images that are liked by a certain user?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to create a variable that contains the last 7 images that have been liked by a user with certain id so I can pass that variable to my view. I believe I have to use `whereHas()` but so far nothing I've tried work so it's probable I might be doing it wrong.

The tables I have are:

```
Table: Votes
Columns: id, user_id, image_id, vote

Table: Users
Columns: id, username, password

Table: Images
Columns: id, name, user_id, path
```

In the votes table, if the vote value is 1, it is a like and of it is 0, it is a dislike.

I have models for the 3 tables like this:

```
Image

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Image extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }


    public function votes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Vote');
    }


}
```

User:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class User extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
    use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
    public function images(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\Image');
    }

    public function votes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Vote');
    }

}
```

Vote:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Vote extends Model
{
    public function images(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Images');
    }
}
```

I was able to figure something close to what I have in mind:

```
$likedImages = Image::where('parent_id', NULL)->whereHas('votes', function($q) use ($vote) {
    return $q->where('vote', $vote);
})->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(7)->get();
```

Unfortunately, this gets liked images by everyone and not just the specific user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally `whereHas()` will do the trick, if you want the images that has been voted you do something like

```
Image::whereHas('votes',function($votes) {
    //if you want to get only votes with 1 you do
    $votes->where('vote',1);
})
//if you want to get the latest 7 images you order them and take 7
->orderBy('id','DESC')
->take(7)
->get();
```

That will get you all the images that has a `votes` row, If that fails, maybe your relationships are not set properly.

Comment: What do you mean by the //more query if you want comment? Also I'm trying to only get images which have a vote of 1 which means it's a like vote.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Vote` model, and fetch the recent 7 votes ***where the like value is 1*** and `LEFT JOIN` the images table.

*I am not an ORM specialist but...*

An untested example:

```
$votes = Vote::where([
        ["user_id", "=", $userId],
        ["vote", "=", 1]])->leftJoin("images", "user_id", "=", "images.user_id")->latest()->take(7);
```

Again, this is untested, but I gave you the idea.